# Google Sign In Integration Testing Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I have implemented Google Sign In using Firebase, but somehow while performing the Integration Testing, I am not able to click the different email address options when the default dialog box opens to sign in. Is there any way I can click on the email given in the dialog box and navigate to the next screen.
The test for finding the login button passess successfully, but the testing app closes once the test has passed not clicking any of the given email addressess on the dialog box.
Attaching screen shots of start screen and email dialog box for better understanding.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Code

```
void main() {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  group('end-to-end test', () {
    var log = find.byType(LoginButton);

    testWidgets('Login Button Test', (tester) async {
      app.main();
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      await tester.tap(log);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    });
  });
}
```